# OpenstreetmapX.jl routing using subnetworks

Tags: julia

I am using `OpenstreetmapX.jl` library to calculate routes between to points of my OSM network.

Is there any way to obtain such routes limiting the results to paths of a predefined sub network?

For instance, I would like to calculate the route between two points **but** only using secondary roadways.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you would like to create a separate `MapData` object for processing such data. There is a nice tool [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) that allows to filter out specific route types before importing data to Julia.
In this way you can have separate representations of your map data.

However, if you want to operate directly on the `MapData` object you could set the distance weights to `Inf` and which would force the routing algorithm to avoid such edges or return `Inf` route length.

Suppose you have the map from the tutorials:

```
using OpenStreetMapX, Graphs
map_file_path = joinpath(dirname(pathof(OpenStreetMapX)),"..","test/data/reno_east3.osm")
mx = get_map_data(map_file_path, use_cache=false);
```

Than you could do to filter out secondary routes:

```
m2 = deepcopy(mx)
edgs = collect(edges(mx.g))[findall(!=(4), mx.class)]
setindex!.(Ref(m2.w), Inf, src.(edgs), dst.(edgs))
```

Now the selected route will differ between `mx` and `m2`:

```
julia> shortest_route(mx,    3073938243, 3101115892)
([3073938243, 3073938154, 140340636, 140340638, 3101117891, 3101115892], 549.9261168024648, 32.32592992211371)

julia> shortest_route(m2,    3073938243, 3101115892)
([3073938243, 140533189, 140533195, 3101115892], 617.4395184717641, 54.94654519330738)
```